# Enforce different value constructors in functions signature

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, dependent-type, data-kinds

I am handling currencies and currency operations. I want operations to be type safe, but I also need to store different currencies together in a collection so I can search them.

These two goals seem to clash.

I can implement it with an option type, but I don't get type safety in operations:

```hs
type Number = Rational

data Currency = USD | EUR | GBP

data Value = Value Number Currency

-- I can have this
type ConversionRate = (Currency, Currency, Number)

conversionRates :: [ConversionRate]
conversionRates = [(GBP, EUR, 1.2)]

-- This is not typesafe and would allow summing different currencies
sumValue :: Value -> Value -> Value
sumValue = undefined

-- This is also not typesafe
convert :: ConversionRate -> Value -> Currency -> Maybe Value
convert = undefined
```

Or I can use a type for each currency, but I can't easily create and handle their exchange rates.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

type Number = Rational

data USD = USD
data EUR = EUR
data GBP = GBP

class Currency a

instance Currency USD
instance Currency EUR
instance Currency GBP

data Value a where
    Value :: Currency a => a -> Value a

data ConversionRate a b where
    ConversionRate :: (Currency a, Currency b) => Number -> ConversionRate a b

-- Now I can have type-safe currency operations
sumValue :: Currency a => Value a -> Value a
sumValue = undefined

-- And I can make sure my conversions make sense
convert :: ConversionRate a b -> Value a -> b
convert = undefined

-- But I can't hold a list of conversion rates that I can easily manipulate
type ConversionRates = ??
```

### How I'm currently doing it

My current solution is an isomorphism between currencies as different types and a currency option type in the hope of having the best of both worlds in different parts of the program. But this is a mess to work with.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
type Number = Rational

data Symbol = USD | EUR | GBP

data Dollar = Dollar
data Euro = Euro
data Pound = Pound

class Currency a where
    toSymbol :: a -> Symbol

instance Currency Dollar where toSymbol _ = USD
instance Currency Euro where toSymbol _ = EUR
instance Currency Pound where toSymbol _ = GBP

data Wrapper = forall a. Currency a => Wrapper a

toCurrency :: Symbol -> Wrapper
```

***How can I have type safety in some functions and the convenience of same-type values in other functions?***. Looks like a job for `DataKinds` but I don't see how it can help.

Keep in mind that I don't have all the data at coding time. It will be fetched from an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee this is the "best" approach for any reasonable notion of "best", but here's a try.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables,
  AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

module Currency where

type Number = Rational
```

We start by defining a `Currency` type with some associated auxiliary machinery.

```
data Currency = USD | EUR | GBP
```

We add an an associated singleton GADT.

```
-- Singleton type for Currency
data SCurrency (cur :: Currency) where
    S_USD :: SCurrency 'USD
    S_EUR :: SCurrency 'EUR
    S_GBP :: SCurrency 'GBP
```

We also define a helper class to link the two types (basic and singleton). We could do without, but it's convenient.

```
-- Helper class
class CCurrency (cur :: Currency) where
    sing :: SCurrency cur
instance CCurrency 'USD where sing = S_USD
instance CCurrency 'EUR where sing = S_EUR
instance CCurrency 'GBP where sing = S_GBP
```

We'll need an heterogeneous equality operator on the singleton type.

```
-- Like (==), but working on potentially different types
sameCur :: SCurrency cur1 -> SCurrency cur2 -> Bool
sameCur S_USD S_USD = True
sameCur S_EUR S_EUR = True
sameCur S_GBP S_GBP = True
sameCur _     _     = False
```

Ideally we should have `sameCur :: SCurrency cur1 -> SCurrency cur2 -> Either (cur1 :~: cur2) ((cur1 :~: cur2) -> Void)` but a boolean is enough for our purposes.

End of the preliminaries. We can now define a type for values with a currency known at compile time.

```
data Value (cur :: Currency) =  Value Number
```

We also have a type for values with a currency known only at runtime

```
data AnyValue where
    AnyValue :: CCurrency cur => Value cur -> AnyValue
```

Conversion rate are similar to the original code, except they carry singletons.

```
data ConversionRate where
    CR :: SCurrency cur1 -> SCurrency cur2 -> Number -> ConversionRate

conversionRates :: [ConversionRate]
conversionRates = [CR S_GBP S_EUR 1.2]
```

We can now define a typesafe sum.

```
sumValue :: Value cur -> Value cur -> Value cur
sumValue (Value x) (Value y) = Value (x+y)
```

We can also write a typesafe conversion, in two flavors.

```
convert :: forall newCur. CCurrency newCur =>
           ConversionRate
        -> AnyValue
        -> Maybe (Value newCur)
convert (CR old new rate) (AnyValue (Value val :: Value cur)) =
    if sameCur old (sing @ cur) && sameCur new (sing @ newCur)
    then Just $ Value $ val*rate
    else Nothing

convert' :: forall oldCur newCur. (CCurrency oldCur, CCurrency newCur) =>
            ConversionRate
         -> Value oldCur
         -> Maybe (Value newCur)
convert' cr val = convert cr (AnyValue val)
```

Comment: Wow, that was quite a ride! Thanks a lot for that. I will try it.

Comment: @MarceloLazaroni I think the preliminary code above can be autogenerated using the [singletons](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) package, relieving the effort, but it's still useful to know what's going on and being able to write it manually.